# Hard power-off as a requirement. How to safely enable?

Tags: linux, sync, power, read-only

I need to configure a Ubuntu 16.04 Linux system such that it withstands being hard powered-off regularly.

For regular operation there's basically no writing going on, so a read-only file system might be an option. However for things like remote access with TeamViewer I could imagine that this might lead to problems. I've tried read only for something else in the past and it lead to some unexpected issues.

This system isn't life-critical, so a 99.0% safety is enough and right now it's more important to get it done in a simple way.

What simple options are there?

Comment: A Linux system usually does need to write some files. So a read-only filesystem requires a read-write overlay. Like live systems.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As long as your filesystem supports journaling (and all of the "recent" ones do), you should be fine.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Journaling_file_system

Comment: Good suggestion, except that this just makes recovery easier. If you need to recover, that still means down-time. Preventing it a better cause, or perhaps a combination of the two? I still think this answer is helpful, so a +1 from me regardless.

Comment: @LPChip: A journalled filesystem doesn't need _manual_ recovery often, does it? At least NTFS and ext4 perform any necessary recovery themselves. I guess one could extend it by making data journalled (and/or copy-on-write) as well...

Comment: @grawity I am not that familiar with journalling systems. My response was based on what I read on that wiki. If its my thought, it may also be that of OP's.